# Seating plan for ECE

Tags: trains

We've been allocated seats 34 and 37 on [EuroCity-Express (ECE)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/EuroCity-Express) 451.  I tried to find a seating plan for this train but couldn't find one.  [This forum post appears confusingly unrelated](https://forums.seatcupra.net/index.php?threads/map-updates-ece-2017-18-2018.439096/) despite talking about ECE maps.  The ticket says they're both aisle seats.  Are those two seats opposite each other, adjacent with a corridor in-between, behind each other, or none of those?

The Man in Seat 61 has a [page with Europe train seat plans](https://www.seat61.com/Europe-train-seat-plans.htm).  Although he links to [this Dropbox page](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ct7lf8p40719zj3/etr610.pdf?dl=0) for the Switzerland-Milan EuroCity, it doesn't seem to cover the EuroCity-Express.  I can't find it at [vagonweb](https://www.vagonweb.cz/?&lang=en) either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia article you linked shows that the EuroCity-Express uses ETR610 trains. Since your other sources link to the seating plan for the Frecciargento ETR610 trains, I think it's fair to assume that the interior layout is the same. But to verify this, I found a few YouTube videos and checked the seat numbers in them. In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBSjc7z5lvE) for instance the seat numbers match up perfectly with the ones in your link.

TL;DR: [The dropbox page you linked to from Seat61](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ct7lf8p40719zj3/etr610.pdf?dl=0) is correct for the EuroCity-Express train as well as the Frecciargento.